# How can I require a Yarn package in the Rails assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yarnpkg, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have installed the package [progressbar.js](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/progressbar.js) using `$ yarn add progressbar.js`. Now I am trying to require it by adding `//= require progressbar.js` to my `application.js`, but that gives me an error every time I try to load a page:

> ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'progressbar.js' with type 'application/javascript'...

I have successfully used the same process to install and require [jquery](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/jquery). Trying another package with a dot in its name like [ipaddr.js](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/ipaddr.js) fails with the same error, so I suspect that there's something special going on with packages with a dot in their name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should require exact the js file of this lib:

```
//= require progressbar.js/src/main.js
```

or

```
//= require ipaddr.js/lib/ipaddr.js
```

Comment: Gonna go with `//= require progressbar.js/dist/progressbar.js` instead, since that's the same path used to require _jquery_.

Comment: @esBeee because you must require `js` file, exact the file of lib, the `progressbar.js` it's just a name of the lib. Here is a tip for you, check `package.json` the `main` section. https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/blob/master/package.json

Comment: well, but I wondered why you don't have to specify a JS file for other packages, like `//= require jquery`? In that case, it automatically requires `jquery/dist/jquery.js`. A similarily named file exists for `progressbar.js`: `progressbar.js/dist/progressbar.js`. Probably the `.js` in the package name `progressbar.js` confuses rails. Maybe it would work if the file was named `progressbar.js/dist/progressbar.js.js` or the package name was just `progressbar`.

Comment: it's totaly depends on the assets load paths.